# Update field Error in MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, modx

I am trying to update a MySQL database field (decrease the value by 1) in a specific row (ID)  of the "places" column, as long as the number in the field is greater than 0.

(see the example statement below)

```
UPDATE table SET places = places - 1 WHERE id = $id AND places > 0
```

The statement below fails apart from changing the value of the field to zero.
I would be grateful if anyone can help with the syntax error.

```
if($id){
    global $modx;
    $table = "`database_name`.`table_name`";
    $update_seats = "`places` - 1";
    $result = $modx->db->update( '`places` = "' . $update_seats . '"', $table, '`id` = "' . $id . '" AND `places` > 0' );
    return $result;         // Returns 'true' on success, 'false' on failure.
    }
```

Comment: Maybe if you checked for an error message and told us what it is or looked at your mysql query log to see what was actually being sent to the server then it might make it easier to help you - you may even be able to solve the problem yourself. (looking at the code, I think it's highly unlikely that the method call is generating SQL anything like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enclosed new value of field in double quotes

```
$result = $modx->db->update( '`places` = "' . $update_seats . '"', $table, '`id` = "' . $id . '" AND `places` > 0' );
```

what is evaluated as string in MySQL query. Remove double quotes here

```
'`places` = "' . $update_seats . '"'
```

so that it looks like this

```
$result = $modx->db->update( '`places` = ' . $update_seats, $table, '`id` = "' . $id . '" AND `places` > 0' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent responses. The solution above worked.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks ok, if you need to set minimum value of `1` to `places` you should simply change the query accordingly:

```
UPDATE table SET places = places - 1 WHERE id = $id AND places > 1
```